# How to reference array item examples in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

Using this schema definition:

```yaml
schemas:
  AllContacts:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/ContactModel1'
    example:
      - id: 1
        firstName: Sherlock
        lastName: Holmes
      - id: 2
        firstName: John
        lastName: Watson
```

I get this expected result:

```js
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "firstName": "Sherlock",
     "lastName": "Holmes"
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Watson"
  }
]
```

Now I'd like to reuse the Holmes example for both the single user (`ContactModel1`) and as part of an array of users (`AllContacts`). But if I use the referenced examples:

```yaml
schemas:

  AllContacts:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/ContactModel1'
    example:
      Homes:
        $ref: '#/components/examples/Homes'
      Watson:
        $ref: '#/components/examples/Watson'

  examples:

    Holmes:
      value:
        id: 1
        first_name: Sherlock
        last_name: Holmes

    Watson:
      value:
        id: 2
        first_name: John
        last_name: Watson
```

I get this unexpected result in Swagger UI:

```js
[
  {
    "value": {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Sherlock",
      "last_name": "Holmes",
    },
    "$$ref": "#/components/examples/Holmes"
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Watson",
    },
    "$$ref": "#/components/examples/Watson"
  }
]
```

and a similar unexpected example for `GET /user/1`:

```js
[
  {
    "value": {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Sherlock",
      "last_name": "Holmes",
    },
    "$$ref": "#/components/examples/Holmes"
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using this doc as reference:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/#reuse

Comment: The Homes (and Watson) lines under EXAMPLE is missing the COLON by mistake in this question, not in my code.

My appologies

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is NOT a valid definition:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    AllContacts:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ContactModel1'
      example:
        Homes:
          $ref: '#/components/examples/Homes'
        Watson:
          $ref: '#/components/examples/Watson'
```

1) The `example` syntax is wrong. OpenAPI 3.0 has two keywords for examples - `example` (singular) and `examples` (plural). They work differently:

- **`example` requires an inline example and does not support `$ref`**.
- `examples` is a map (collection) of named examples. It supports `$ref` - but **you can only `$ref` whole examples, not individual parts of an example**. This also means it's not possible to build an example from multiple `$ref`s. Note that not all elements support plural `examples`.

**Note for Swagger UI users:** Swagger UI currently supports `example` (singular) but not `examples` (plural). Support for `examples` is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2651).

2) The [Schema Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#schemaObject) only supports singular `example` but not plural `examples`. In other words, **schemas support inline examples only**.

3) In OpenAPI 3.0, schema references use the format `#/components/schemas/...`, not `#/definitions/...`

> I'd like to use the same EXAMPLE definition for Holmes in both cases, the array of users and the single user.

There's no way to reuse a part of an example in this case. You'll have to repeat the example value in both schemas:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ContactModel1:
      type: object
      properties:
        ...
      example:
        id: 1
        first_name: Sherlock
        last_name: Holmes

    AllContacts:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/ContactModel1'
      example:
        - id: 1
          first_name: Sherlock
          last_name: Holmes
        - id: 2
          first_name: John
          last_name: Watson
```

Comment: The COLON was just an error in my question, not by actual code.

I was afraid this was to be the answer.

Thx

Answer (score -1):

Use **allOf** for arrays

```
components:
  schemas:
    AllContacts:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ContactModel1'
      example:
        allOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/examples/Homes'
          - $ref: '#/components/examples/Watson'
```