# Why did a schema inherit examples of array items from its subschema?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

OpenAPI 3.0.0, Swagger online editor.

I composed subschemas via the `allOf` discriminator and set the `example` field for a resulting schema. Swagger UI, however, didn't provide the example as-is.

The schema contained an array originating from the subschema. The array inherited example items from the subschema and extended the list with the examples from the schema.

### Example

Let's say we have two schemas:

```yaml
Cats:
  type: object
  properties:
    cats:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          fluffiness:
            type: integer
          names:
            type: string
  example:
    cats:
      - fluffiness: 9
        names: "Felix"
      - fluffiness: 10
        names: "Neko"
        

FluffiestCats:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cats'
    - type: object
      properties:
        date:
          type: string
          format: "date"
  example:
    cats:
      - fluffiness: 10
        names: "Luna" 
      - fluffiness: 10
        names: "Meowie"
    date: "17-01-2021"
```

Responding to some request, the API retrieves the fluffiest cats, referencing `#/components/schemas/FluffiestCats/`. Swagger UI generates the following response example.

```json
{
  "cats": [
    {
      "fluffiness": 9,
      "names": "Felix"
    },
    {
      "fluffiness": 10,
      "names": "Neko"
    },
    {
      "fluffiness": 10,
      "names": "Luna"
    },
    {
      "fluffiness": 10,
      "names": "Meowie"
    }
  ],
  "date": "17-01-2021"
}
```

Swagger UI takes two examples from the *subschema* example items. The *provided* example doesn't override the *subschema* example.

1. Does this behaviour contradict the specification? According to the description, it seems the [Schema Object's](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md#schemaObject) `example` field doesn't imply *override*, in contrast to the [Parameter Object's](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md#parameterObject) `example` field.
2. How can I override the subschema example? Or do I have to recreate the schema without using the `allOf`?

### References

1. [How to reference array item examples in OpenAPI 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839121/how-to-reference-array-item-examples-in-openapi-3)
2. [OpenAPI 3.0.0 specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It was an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4175) with Swagger UI.

Fixed in Swagger UI 4.5.0 and Swagger Editor 4.0.7.

Comment: Fixed in the Swagger-JS 3.8.14. release.